# Meteor Meteorite npm version lock

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have update Meteor on the last version and this version don't work with Meteorite.

Here my "sudo mrt" logs

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/examples/fileapi/public/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/examples/serverstats-express_3/public/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/examples/serverstats/public/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/winston/node_modules/pkginfo/docs/pkginfo.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/meteor-ejson/node_modules/underscore/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/pkginfo/docs/pkginfo.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/docs/prompt.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/colors/example.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/test/_/argv.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/test/_/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/bool.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/boolean_double.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/boolean_single.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/default_hash.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/default_singles.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/divide.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count_options.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count_wrap.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/nonopt.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/reflect.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/short.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/string.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/xup.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/rimraf/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I don't know where the error come from.

Any idea?

Thank you !

Answer (score 10):

Problem resolved, just removed the directory node modules and it fixed everything.
rm -rf node_modules

Comment: Where is the node_modules directory located?

Comment: According to your edit history, you had an error like that: `npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.x, required by meteor-npm@0.1.6
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.3.x, required by meteor-npm@0.1.6
npm ERR! not ok code 0`

I am having this error, what have you done to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, you should not run mrt as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update node also

You might have to update your node installation at your root level

use `sudo npm update`

then re-run `sudo mrt` and see if this fixes the issue